# How to set launch arguments programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I know that I can set launch arguments in the screen below in XCode, but is there a way to set them programmatically?

The reason is that I have a .swift file that contains test data. I want to read the data from that file and pass it into launch arguments in order to configure the app on launch. Does anyone know how this can be done?

[image]

Comment: I am fairly certain that isn't possible in any direct manor. It may be possible by scripting a solution that uses AppleScript, and scripted mouse clicks, etc - but it would be very much a hack.

Comment: Why don't you want to read the data from file and use it directly after app launches?

Comment: I just know that you can do it on UITests by writing:

XCUIApplication().launchArguments.append("YOUR_ARGUMENT")